# c# chat client with socket io

Tags: c#, sockets, chat

I am building a chat client in C# with socket io, the server is in nodejs, my problem is when reciving messages from other users, how could I structure the program to be able to open a different window for each user that sends me a message without mixing the messages. I hope I have explained well. Thanks.

[The idea of what i want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voqfk.png)

Comment: it really depends on message structure which we're not aware of.

Comment: By creating channels this may help:https://github.com/sacOO7/SocketclusterClientDotNet

Comment: The message structure is {from: xxx, to: xxx, message: xxx}, is just a json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have 'from' field in a message, it shouldn't be a problem, you can divide your messages by this field and then store a collection of all your chats somewhere, e.g.:

```
Dictionary<string, ChatWindow> chatWindows = new Dictionary<string, ChatWindow>();
...
public void ProcessMessage(Message message)
{
    ChatWindow chatWindow;
    if(!chatWindows.TryGetValue(message.From, out chatWindow))
    {
        chatWindow = new ChatWindow();
        chatWindows[message.From] = chatWindow;
    }

    chatWindow.AddMessage(message);
}
```

It's just some kind of pseudo code, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think the best option to do that ist to use WPF and custom controls. With this you can easily make chat-bubbles and add them to a board without loosing the overview.

Its also better because the working code (c#) is seperated from the design code (xaml).
I hope it helps you.

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: I do not really understand what you mean